# bringing Grafana to HTML page with its functionality using Object or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grafana

I am trying to load a page without using `iframe`. Please take a note of this.

I have built a grafana dashboard on my server and would like to present it on the website. But there is no such functionality offered by grafana.

So I tried the other methods by taking a shareable URL of the grafana and calling it through `jQuery` like this:

```
<script>$("#testLoad").load("http://grafanawebsiteURL:Port/dashboard/snapshot/1tPknm7rfA5CoeNgAetILYbhcgfl1gEv");</script>
<div id="testLoad"></div>
```

But I failed as I could see anything on the screen and there was no error on the console window.

Then I tried `<object>` tag. I got success partially as I was able to display the dashboard but was not able to drag and drop the dashboard panel. even the dashboard looks shabby and weird, means not getting fit to my screen and going beyond.

Have a look at the current image of the dashboard:
[image: current image]

just have a look where you will see all the graph panels got stretched out of the window and I need to scroll left to right for viewing the graphs.

What I would like to have in the view, have a look at the image:
[image: what is needed.]

I want to know how I can get the drag and drop functionality exactly like grafana and how to fit the container of the grafana on the screen using `object` or and other methodology.

Here is the `object` code:

```
<div><object type="text/html" data="http://grafanawebsiteURL:Port/dashboard/snapshot/1tPknm7rfA5CoeNgAetILYbhcgfl1gEv" style="width:300%; height:300%"></object></div>
```

I hope to hear solution and advice for this situation.

Comment: Is there someone having idea and can help me?

Comment: Does anyone needs my live link for checking the demo? Please let me know. I think this will be violation if I place any live link here on Stackoverflow